# How to verify two randomly generated numbers are distinct without revealing them

Tags: cryptography

Let's assume a scenario: X and Y separately generate two random numbers a and b respectively. both a and b are between 0- 100. How can both X and Y verify that whether a and b are two distinct numbers without revealing the actual numbers to each other.

One way could be hash the numbers and share the hash value and if the hashes doesn't matches, then they are distinct  numbers. But the problem is since a and be range from 0-100, it can be easily brute forced to get the pre-image

Comment: This isn't a programming or development issue and is offtopic for StackOverflow, but is ontopic at https://cryptography.stackexchange.com where it fits in the category (tag) [zero-knowledge proofs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-knowledge-proofs)